# How can I import WebStorm formatter config to VSCode Prettier?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm, prettier, formatter

I′m using VSCode & my co-worker use WebStorm. Our formatter behave differently and makes us confuse.

Is there a way to make both formatters behave the same?

How can I import WebStorm formatter config to VSCode?

Any suggestion can be helpful.

Comment: Just agree on one formatting. You dont need to "import" anything. Just agree on a syntax styling, like tabs/white space, new lines, etc.

Comment: Well, if both of you are using Prettier then just keep using it -- WebStorm supports Prettier and can run it on Save (just not sure if it will be run instead of or after the WebStorm's own formatter; but obviously, when typing the code the IDE will use built-in formatter at that time and Prettier on Save).

Comment: Im using prettier in VSCode & my coworkers uses webstorm with built-in formatter .

Comment: *"Im using prettier in VSCode & my coworkers uses webstorm with built-in formatter ."* So tell him to use Prettier as well. It's easy and does not require anything crazy and work transparently for him (on Save): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/prettier.html Unified solutions are the best as they work across editors/IDEs.

Comment: maybe it's possible, but I'll bet on it not being possible 100%. I second the suggestion that you and your coworker look for something that is "supported by" / integratable into both editors.